# Eclipse started to look different

Tags: eclipse

I have recently noticed eclipse started to look A LOT different than it used to and I do not like the change. I attached to images of before and after. Does anyone know what might have happened? If this is helps any I upgraded from jdk 7 to jdk 8. I have a youtube channel on coding and I think the font looks bad so I don't want people not watching because of it.

**Picture of Before (This is what I want it to look like):**

[image: Picture of Before (This is what I want it to look like)]

**Picture of After (I want this to look like before):**

[image: Picture of After (I want this to look like before)]

Comment: Sorry if the actual code is different, don't worry about that. I mean the font and the shape of the tabs.

Comment: You can change the theme, including the font, in your preferences. Not saying this is the answer, I'm not sure why your UI changed, but if the font is the issue, you can easily modify it, as well as other settings such as UI color scheme.

Comment: I changed the font... but that isn't really the real problem. The problem is how the workspace looks (the tabs are rectangles, there are spots shaded grey, and the icons on the top are farther apart)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the theme to Indigo via preferences?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-enabling theming.

Note: You can change the **Colors and Fonts** there as well. (IntelliJ has a better font IMO, anyway)

If that is broken (and you really care about eye-candy that much) then re-download Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your own answer or accept this one if it was the solution

Answer (score -1):

I figured everything out. I went to `Window -> Preferences -> General-> Appearance` then changed theme to windows and colors were set to default then it worked!

To change the font, I went to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts` then changed the font to Consolas.

Then everything was back to normal.